# How can I use pollen?

Tags: baking

My dad and I bought some pollen at a fair about five years ago, and other than taking a little handful out and munching it every so often, we've never really used it.

How can I use pollen?

Comment: Welcome! You may want to read this very old [Meta Q/A](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/740/can-i-ask-about-how-to-use-a-specific-ingredient-aka-culinary-uses-guidelines).

Comment: @Stephie Thanks for the link. I think this falls more into the "rare and unusual" and "not usually associated with cooking but edible" category.

Comment: I would not classify pollen as “not usually a food item”, but am willing to wait a bit and see what the community thinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not that many uses for pollen tbh. one of the ways i used it is make smoothies with it or mix it into some ice cream, even perhaps a garnish or a topping for delicacies. 
Bee pollen pairs particularly well with honey mustard dressings, poppy seed dressings or slightly sweet vinaigrette so mix it into your salads.